# Get a list of paths through a graph

Tags: haskell

I am trying to get a list of lists of all possible paths through a graph with a given starting point and a destination. 
The graph is given as follows:

```
data Node = N1 | N2 | N3 | N4 | N5 deriving (Show, Eq)

neighbor :: Node -> [Node]
neighbor N1 = [N2, N4, N5]
neighbor N2 = [N1, N3]
neighbor N3 = [N1, N4, N5]
neighbor N4 = [N5]
neighbor N5 = [N1]
```

The problem is: given a start node and a destination node (e.g. start node = N1 and destination = N4) all possible routes, without cycles, leading from start to destination shall be the result. In the example given it would be:

```
[[N1, N2, N3, N4],[N1, N4]]
```

The function I am trying to solve this problem with is:

```
generatePaths :: (Node -> [Node]) -> Node -> Node -> [[Node]]
```

Here the first argument shall be the neighbor function, the second the start node and the third the destinaion node.

My main problem is that I find now way on how to iterate through all neighbors and call `generatePaths` with every neighbor as new start node.

Any help is highly appreciated

EDIT:
Thx to Krom and RoadRunner I came up with an implementation.

```
dfs_h :: (Node -> [Node]) -> [Node] -> [Node] -> Node -> [[Node]]
dfs_h graph visited [] _ = [visited]
dfs_h graph visited (n:ns) end 
    | elem n visited = (dfs_h graph visited ns end)
    | elem end ns = [reverse (end:visited)] ++ (dfs_h graph visited (n:[neigh|neigh <- ns, neigh /= end]) end)
    | n == end = [reverse (end:visited)] ++ (dfs_h graph visited ns end)
    | otherwise = dfs_h graph (n:visited) ((graph n) ++ ns) end

dfs start end = filter (\x -> elem end x) (dfs_h neighbor [start] (neighbor start) end
```

I am aware that this isn't the most beautiful solution, just the first I came up with.

EDIT2: 
But a problem with this algorithm is when the graph looks like this:

```
neighbor :: Node -> [Node]
neighbor N1 = [N2, N3]
neighbor N2 = [N5]
neighbor N3 = [N4]
neighbor N4 = [N2, N1]
neighbor N5 = [N1]
```

and a path from `N1` to `N4` shall be found then the result of the function is

```
[[N1, N2, N5, N3, N4]]
```

Now I don't what to implement so that the `N2` and `N5`, which should not be part of the solution, don't get included. 
Any suggenstions?

Comment: I can't give you a faulty implementation unfortunately, because I deleted it to start from scratch. But my approach would be a helper function like this:
`generatePaths_h :: (Node -> [Node]) -> [Node] -> [Node] -> Node -> Node -> [[Node]]`
where the second argument now is the path leading to the current node, and the second argument shall be a list of neighbors that still has to be iterated through. The remaining arguments are the same as in `generatePaths`

Comment: Is the graph directed? Which algorithm to solve this problem did you try to implement?

Comment: Just use the depth first search algorithm if the graph is directed.

Comment: Thx for the hint to dfs. I already thought about that but threw the idea away because I found no way to generate a list of lists (i.e. list of paths). 
I post my implementation in the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your recursion step

```
| otherwise = dfs_h graph (n:visited) ((graph n) ++ ns) end
```

looks weird. You try to handle the case that `n` is a valid intermediate node on your path. For the recursion, you therefore collect `n` in the `visited` log. The problem is, that `ns` - a list of further intermediate nodes in the current step - will be handled in the recursion step. Instead it should be handled with the unmodified current set of visited nodes.

A simpler solution would be to separate you logging from the  computed intermediate results:

```
generatePaths :: (Node -> [Node]) -> Node -> Node -> [[Node]]
generatePaths successors start end = map reverse $ dfs [] [[]] start
  where
    dfs :: [Node] -> [[Node]] -> Node -> [[Node]]
    dfs visited acc next
      -- destination reached, add final step
      | next == end = step next acc
      -- circle detected, reject paths
      | next `elem` visited = []
      -- make one step, continue recursion
      | otherwise = concat . map (dfs (next:visited) (step next acc)) $ successors next

    -- add `next` to each of the current paths
    step :: Node -> [[Node]] -> [[Node]]
    step next = map ((:) next)
```

Comment: sorry for the late response. Yeah I have to agree. Your function is much simpler and understandable than my attempt. Thx.